# Allowing user to select radscheduler timeline's scale

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-scheduler

I am trying to use radscheduler to create a timeline view to display list of tasks currently in the database. I want user to be able to change the timeline view's scale to days or weeks, based on the information required. So, user can just select one week, and expand it to see dates, or select one date and expand to see hourly breakdown.

I am unable to find any way to do that. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Set TimelineView-UserSelectable="true"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.